# How to clean up divs contents?

Tags: javascript, html

I heared that simply to say `document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML = "";` is not safe for future divId contents editing via JS so how to clean up divs contents safely?

Comment: you don't want to delete is manually?

Comment: I ment when I call some function I need to clean it. And I have other to fill it=)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe?

Comment: @PeeHaa I was wondering the same thing. I have a vague recollection of some issues with element ids in IE, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: The risk in using innerHTML is malformed html strings, as different browsers will do things differently. innerHTML is also a bit of a sledgehammer: useful for quickly creating/destroying, but not quite as useful when you just need to make some fine adjustments.

Comment: I think the only risk would be if the browser is older and does not have that as an option. Not sure when most browsers started implementing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something similar to Felix Kling, only diffirence is that I wanted to pass the id or the reference. So I wrote it like this:

```
function removeAllChildNodes(node) {
    i = (typeof(node) == "object") ? node : document.getElementById(node);

    while (i.hasChildNodes()) {
        i.removeChild(i.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What should always work is:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divId');
while(div.hasChildNodes()) {
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

`innerHTML` is not part of any specification but is widely supported by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the innerHTML attribute to nothing will eliminate any DOM nodes withing the specified DIV. There is no risk of "safety".

You can do this safely :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is where JS frameworks, such as jQuery, come to light... they are optimized for cross-browser security - which includes secure DOM element removal, although you will loose a bit of computing speed (setting innerHTML is always the fastest way)

as for others wondering about security of this, some browsers (notably MSIE) have flaws that would crash the browser or allow malicious procedures to be executed on client's side under certain conditions, so that's why setting innerHTML might not be as secure as people use to think ;-)